# How to use a user-defined data C structure into an R package

Tags: r, package, rcpp

This minimal example compiles when I "source" the file:

```
/*
        read_header.c
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <RcppCommon.h>

typedef struct {
    int my_data;
} MY_HEADER_INFO;

namespace Rcpp {
  template <> SEXP wrap(const MY_HEADER_INFO& x);
}

#include <Rcpp.h>
namespace Rcpp {
 template <>
 SEXP wrap(const MY_HEADER_INFO& x) {
   std::vector<std::string> names;
   std::vector<SEXP> elements(1);
   // do something with the elements and names
   names.push_back("my_data");
   elements[0] = Rcpp::wrap( x.my_data );
 };
}

//' @export
// [[Rcpp::export]]
MY_HEADER_INFO read_header() {
    MY_HEADER_INFO *header;
  
  header = (MY_HEADER_INFO*)malloc(sizeof(MY_HEADER_INFO));
  memset(header, 0, sizeof(MY_HEADER_INFO));
  
    return *header;
}
```

When I try to build it in RStudio into a package (CMD + SHIFT + B), I get the following, long, error message, that clearly lists the problem is my user-defined return structure, MY_HEADER_INFO:

DESCRIPTION

```
Package: myPackage
Type: Package
Title: What the Package Does (Title Case)
Version: 0.1.0
Depends: R (>= 4.0.0)
License: GPL-3
Encoding: UTF-8
LazyData: true
RoxygenNote: 7.1.0
Imports:
    Rcpp
Suggests: 
    knitr,
    rmarkdown,
    testthat
VignetteBuilder: knitr
LinkingTo: 
    Rcpp
```

NAMESPACE

```
# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand

export(read_header)
```

I receive the following error:

```
==> Rcpp::compileAttributes()

* Updated src/RcppExports.cpp
* Updated R/RcppExports.R

==> devtools::document(roclets = c('rd', 'collate', 'namespace'))

Updating myPackage documentation
Loading myPackage
Re-compiling myPackage
─  installing *source* package ‘myPackage’ ...
   ** using staged installation
   ** libs
   clang++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -std=gnu++11 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include' -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -UNDEBUG -Wall -pedantic -g -O0 -fdiagnostics-color=always -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
   RcppExports.cpp:9:1: error: unknown type name 'MY_HEADER_INFO'
   MY_HEADER_INFO read_header();
   ^
   1 error generated.
   make: *** [RcppExports.o] Error 1
   ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘myPackage’
─  removing ‘/private/var/folders/gl/jvj9b0xn34lgq6_h9370p8q80000gn/T/RtmpLKsw0o/devtools_install_1f333d54be59/myPackage’

Error: System command 'R' failed, exit status: 1, stdout + stderr:
E> * installing *source* package ‘myPackage’ ...
E> ** using staged installation
E> ** libs
E> clang++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -std=gnu++11 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include' -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -UNDEBUG -Wall -pedantic -g -O0 -fdiagnostics-color=always -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
E> RcppExports.cpp:9:1: error: unknown type name 'MY_HEADER_INFO'
E> MY_HEADER_INFO read_header();
E> ^
E> 1 error generated.
E> make: *** [RcppExports.o] Error 1
E> ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘myPackage’
E> * removing ‘/private/var/folders/gl/jvj9b0xn34lgq6_h9370p8q80000gn/T/RtmpLKsw0o/devtools_install_1f333d54be59/myPackage’

 Stack trace:

 1. base:::suppressPackageStartupMessages({ ...
 2. base:::withCallingHandlers(expr, packageStartupMessage = function(c) tryInv ...
 3. devtools::document(roclets = c("rd", "collate", "namespace"))
 4. withr::with_envvar(r_env_vars(), roxygen2::roxygenise(pkg$path,  ...
 5. base:::force(code)
 6. roxygen2::roxygenise(pkg$path, roclets, load_code = load_code)
 7. roxygen2:::load_code(base_path)
 8. pkgload::load_all(path, helpers = FALSE, attach_testthat = FALSE)
 9. pkgbuild::compile_dll(path, quiet = quiet)
 10. withr::with_makevars(compiler_flags(TRUE), assignment = "+=",  ...
 11. withr:::with_envvar(c(R_MAKEVARS_USER = makevars_file), { ...
 12. base:::force(code)
 13. base:::force(code)
 14. pkgbuild:::install_min(path, dest = install_dir, components = "libs",  ...
 15. pkgbuild:::rcmd_build_tools("INSTALL", c(path, paste("--library=",  ...
 16. pkgbuild:::with_build_tools(callr::rcmd_safe(..., env = env,  ...
 17. callr::rcmd_safe(..., env = env, spinner = FALSE, show = FALSE,  ...
 18. callr:::run_r(options)
 19. base:::with(options, with_envvar(env, do.call(processx::run,  ...
 20. base:::with.default(options, with_envvar(env, do.call(processx::run,  ...
 21. base:::eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame())
 22. base:::eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame())
 23. callr:::with_envvar(env, do.call(processx::run, c(list(bin, args = real_cmd ...
 24. base:::force(code)
 25. base:::do.call(processx::run, c(list(bin, args = real_cmdargs,  ...
 26. (function (command = NULL, args = character(), error_on_status = TRUE,  ...
 27. throw(new_process_error(res, call = sys.call(), echo = echo,  ...

 x System command 'R' failed, exit status: 1, stdout + stderr:
E> * installing *source* package ‘myPackage’ ...
E> ** using staged installation
E> ** libs
E> clang++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -std=gnu++11 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include' -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -UNDEBUG -Wall -pedantic -g -O0 -fdiagnostics-color=always -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
E> RcppExports.cpp:9:1: error: unknown type name 'MY_HEADER_INFO'
E> MY_HEADER_INFO read_header();
E> ^
E> 1 error generated.
E> make: *** [RcppExports.o] Error 1
E> ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘myPackage’
E> * removing ‘/private/var/folders/gl/jvj9b0xn34lgq6_h9370p8q80000gn/T/RtmpLKsw0o/devtools_install_1f333d54be59/myPackage’ 

Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

The following is written to Rcpp_exports:

```
// Generated by using Rcpp::compileAttributes() -> do not edit by hand
// Generator token: 10BE3573-1514-4C36-9D1C-5A225CD40393

#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// read_header
MY_HEADER_INFO read_header();
RcppExport SEXP _myPackage_read_header() {
BEGIN_RCPP
    Rcpp::RObject rcpp_result_gen;
    Rcpp::RNGScope rcpp_rngScope_gen;
    rcpp_result_gen = Rcpp::wrap(read_header());
    return rcpp_result_gen;
END_RCPP
}

static const R_CallMethodDef CallEntries[] = {
    {"_myPackage_read_header", (DL_FUNC) &_myPackage_read_header, 0},
    {NULL, NULL, 0}
};

RcppExport void R_init_myPackage(DllInfo *dll) {
    R_registerRoutines(dll, NULL, CallEntries, NULL, NULL);
    R_useDynamicSymbols(dll, FALSE);
}
```

If I try to modify this file, however, it all gets written over when I call CMD+SHIFT+B.
Other C programs I've written for this same package that return standard data types (e.g., "std::vector") compile without a problem, both when I "source" the code in the Console and when I build them into a package.

I have read through the Rcpp documentation and related vignettes (and even bought Dirk's book!), but I cannot find how to tell the package builder where the definition of MY_HEADER_INFO is located. How do I tell the package compiler where the definition of this file is located?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That look like another instance of a not-entirely-uncommon problem for which we *do* have a wonderfully simple answer that is somewho less known than it should be.

In short, for a package `<pkg>` (where `<pkg>` is an alias for your package name, with lower or undercase as you please. and obviously no `<` or `>`) please such `struct` (or in the C++ case `class`) or `typedef` or ... definitions into a file `inst/include/<pkg>_types.h` (replacing `<pkg>` with your package name).

If such a file exists, it is automagically included by `RcppExports.cpp` and you are good to go.

Details are in the [Rcpp Attributes vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-attributes.pdf), and a few related forms are allowed as well:

```
src/<pkg>_types.h
src/<pkg>_types.hpp
inst/include/<pkg>_types.h
inst/include/<pkg>_types.hpp
inst/include/<pkg>.h
```

but `inst/include/<pkg>_types.h` may be the most commonly used one. One example of using it via `src/` is [src/RSQLite_types.h](https://github.com/r-dbi/RSQLite/blob/master/src/RSQLite_types.h).  On the other hand, an example of using it in `inst/include/` is [inst/include/RcppQuantuccia_types.h](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppquantuccia/blob/master/inst/include/RcppQuantuccia_types.h) and another, much larger one in [inst/include/RcppGSL_types.h](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppgsl/blob/master/inst/include/RcppGSL_types.h).

Comment: Thank you, Dirk! Your suggestions and pointers have gotten me closer, but I'm still getting something wrong. I made "myPackage_types.h" to "inst/include" with ```#include <Rcpp.h>

namespace Rcpp {
  typedef struct {
    int my_data;
  } MY_HEADER_INFO;

} ``` Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/internal/wrap.h:523:17: error: static_assert failed due to requirement '!sizeof(Rcpp::MY_HEADER_INFO)' "cannot convert type to SEXP"
                   static_assert(!sizeof(T), "cannot convert type to SEXP");
                   ^             ~~~~~~~

Comment: If you can, post a link to code. This is essentially illegible in a comment. But it looks like you have a *new* error (as my recommendation fixed the previous one), now your conversion from your type to `SEXP` is not working.  That is now "simply" a code/design issue for you.

Comment: I agree that you fixed the original question, so I checked this one as "answered" and will ask a new question. Thanks!

Comment: Excellent.  We have a few guides to writing `as<>()` and `wrap()`, starting from simple guides at the Rcpp Gallery, and likely also a few questions here.  Not the easiest of topics but really handy once you have it ...  There are alternatives if you want to get started "sooner".