# Returning a user-defined structure from Rcpp in an R package

Tags: r, package, rcpp

Rcpp is powerful and has worked great in most all cases, but I cannot figure out how to wrap a C-function that returns a user-defined structure into an R package.

DESCRIPTION

```
Package: myPackage
Type: Package
Title: What the Package Does (Title Case)
Version: 0.1.0
Depends: R (>= 4.0.0)
License: GPL-3
Encoding: UTF-8
LazyData: true
RoxygenNote: 7.1.0
Imports:
    Rcpp
Suggests: 
    knitr,
    rmarkdown,
    testthat
VignetteBuilder: knitr
LinkingTo: 
    Rcpp
```

NAMESPACE

```
# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand

importFrom(Rcpp,evalCpp)
export(read_header)
useDynLib(myPackage, .registration = TRUE)
```

Header File ("inst/include/myPackage_types.h")

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

namespace Rcpp {

  typedef struct {
    int my_data;
  } MY_HEADER_INFO;

  template <> SEXP wrap(const MY_HEADER_INFO& x) {
    std::vector<std::string> names;
    std::vector<SEXP> elements(1);
    // do something with the elements and names
    names.push_back("my_data");
    elements[0] = Rcpp::wrap( x.my_data );
    return 0;
  };

}
```

C-code

```
/*
        read_header.c
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <Rcpp.h>
#include "inst/include/myPackage_types.h"

namespace Rcpp {

// [[Rcpp::export]]
  Rcpp::MY_HEADER_INFO read_header() {
    Rcpp::MY_HEADER_INFO *header;
    
    header = (Rcpp::MY_HEADER_INFO*)malloc(sizeof(Rcpp::MY_HEADER_INFO));
    memset(header, 0, sizeof(Rcpp::MY_HEADER_INFO));
    
    return *header;
  }

}
```

When I source (i.e., compile) the C-code, I get the following:

```
Error in dyn.load("/private/var/folders/gl/jvj9b0xn34lgq6_h9370p8q80000gn/T/RtmpYRaBGW/sourceCpp-x86_64-apple-darwin17.0-1.0.4.6/sourcecpp_25a13fe3d7da/sourceCpp_49.so") : 
  unable to load shared object ...
```

When I try to build the package (CMD + Shift + B), I get:

```
clang++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -std=gnu++11 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/include' -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -UNDEBUG -Wall -pedantic -g -O0 -fdiagnostics-color=always -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
   RcppExports.cpp:9:7: error: no type named 'MY_HEADER_INFO' in namespace 'Rcpp'
   Rcpp::MY_HEADER_INFO read_header();
   ~~~~~~^
```

This seems so simple, but I can't find a similar vignetter or example and none of the variations I've tried seem to work. What is the cause of the dynamical loading error for SourceCpp? Why can't the compiler find the code in the header file?

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't this the same question you asked yesterday (https://stackoverflow.com/q/62734032/2554330)? What's new?

Comment: I am not sure of what you have, but from the error, it seems that you have not defined `MY_HEADER_INFO`. The way you have defined it is valid in `C`. in `C++` You should have the structure name immediately after the identifier `struct`. Have you tried that one?

Comment: user2554330, yes, it is similar, but Dirk gave a nice explanation of how Rcpp finds include files (my first question), which helped me get past one error message. Alas, another followed on its heels. The StackOverflow "gods" frown on question-drift, so I thought it best to start a new question following Dirk's answer to the first. Onyambu, I tried "typedef struct MY_HEADER_INFO" in the header file, but the errors were the same. I liked your comment, though, as I feel like I am stuck on something rather trivial (okay, I _hope_its trivial!), and the slightest change will make everything work.

Comment: No, it is not "trivial" as we wrote an entire [pdf vignette](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-extending.pdf)  on the topic. And I guess you didn't help your case by repeating too much of the previous (now solved) question of "how do I make `struct` definition known" obstructing a more minimal view on "how do I add code to map my `struct` to R objects".  And there are no shortcuts or silver bullets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work and have posted my solution to GitHub: git@github.com:markrbower/myPackage.git

The key parts are:
inst/include/myPackage_types.h

```
#include <RcppCommon.h>

namespace Rcpp {
  typedef struct {
    int my_data;
  } MY_HEADER_INFO;

  template <> SEXP wrap(const MY_HEADER_INFO& x);
  
  template<> MY_HEADER_INFO* as(SEXP x);
}
```

read_header.cpp

```
/*
        read_header.c
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "../inst/include/myPackage_types.h"

#include <RcppCommon.h>


namespace Rcpp {

  template <> SEXP wrap(const MY_HEADER_INFO& x);

}

#include <Rcpp.h>

namespace Rcpp {
  template <> SEXP wrap(const MY_HEADER_INFO& x) {
    std::vector<std::string> names;
    std::vector<SEXP> elements(1);
    // do something with the elements and names
    names.push_back("my_data");
    elements[0] = wrap( x.my_data );
    
    Rcpp::List result(elements.size());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < elements.size(); ++i) {
      result[i] = elements[i];
    }
    result.attr("names") = Rcpp::wrap(names);
    // result can be return to R as a list   
    return( result );
  };
}

//' @importFrom Rcpp evalCpp
//' @useDynLib myPackage
//' @export
// [[Rcpp::export]]
  Rcpp::MY_HEADER_INFO read_header() {
    Rcpp::MY_HEADER_INFO *header = NULL;
    
    printf( "%ld\n", sizeof(Rcpp::MY_HEADER_INFO) );
    
    header = (Rcpp::MY_HEADER_INFO*)malloc(sizeof(Rcpp::MY_HEADER_INFO));
    memset(header, 0, sizeof(Rcpp::MY_HEADER_INFO));
    
    header->my_data = 10;
    
    return *header;
}
```

There were two problems. First, I had template definitions under the wrong Rcpp header (put the initial calls after RcppCommon.h and the detailed calls after Rcpp.h). The tutorials and examples warned me not to do that, but I did it, anyway. Second, I found that if you "source" the code and *then* "load" the library, the sourced code will obscure the library code and you will get a "null pointer" error. Running "devtools::check()" showed me that along with noting that the fix is to "rm" the sourced function.

Let me also add that there are two Roxygen comments that I needed to add to my .cpp file to get the appropriate commands to appear in my NAMESPACE file:
//' @importFrom Rcpp evalCpp
//' @useDynLib myPackage

I found an old post where Dirk suggested using the Rcpp.package.skeleton function to build a "baby" project and then slowly add things until you can do what you want. That is **so** much better than the approach I have been using: Start with a complex C program and try to shoehorn my code into Rcpp.